# ONNX converted TensorFlow saved model runs on CPU but not on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, onnxruntime

I converted a tensorflow saved model to ONNX format using tf2onnx :

```
python3 -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model saved_model/ --output onnx/model.onnx --opset 11
```

The conversion worked fine and I can run inference with the ONNX model using CPU.

I installed `onnxruntime-gpu` to run inference with GPU and encountered an error :

```
RuntimeException: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 6 : RUNTIME_EXCEPTION : Non-zero status code returned while running Relu node. Name:'FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/resnet_v1_101/conv1/Relu' Status Message: /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/providers/cuda/cuda_call.cc:97 bool onnxruntime::CudaCall(ERRTYPE, const char*, const char*, ERRTYPE, const char*) [with ERRTYPE = cudaError; bool THRW = true] /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/providers/cuda/cuda_call.cc:91 bool onnxruntime::CudaCall(ERRTYPE, const char*, const char*, ERRTYPE, const char*) [with ERRTYPE = cudaError; bool THRW = true] CUDA failure 2: out of memory ; GPU=0 ; hostname=coincoin; expr=cudaMalloc((void**)&p, size); 
Stacktrace:

Stacktrace:
```

I am the only one using the GPU which is a Titan RTX (24GB of RAM). The model runs fine on GPU using its tensorflow saved model version, with 10GB of the GPU's RAM.

Versions are :

- tensorflow 1.14.0
- CUDA 10.0
- CuDNN 7.6.5
- onnx 1.6.0
- onnxruntime 1.1.0
- tf2onnx 1.9.2
- python 3.6
- Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

according to your information and Versions, maybe two solutions to solve the problem:

- 1. the information is out of memory, please check the gpu memory is available yet, if not available, set the gpu memory:

[image]

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()                                                                           
config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = "0"                                                        
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.1                                            
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

- 2. downgrade onnxruntime-gpu, according to your Versions, CUDA 10.0 matchs with onnxruntime-gpu==1.0.0, not 1.1.0, which needs cuda 11
     https://github.com/Microsoft/onnxruntime/releases/tag/v1.1.0

Comment: 1. GPU memory is fully available at the time of inference. 2. [official doc](https://www.onnxruntime.ai/docs/reference/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html) says CUDA 10 for onnxruntime-gpu 1.1., I had to double check that. 3. I don't see how to use tf session when running with onnx backend. Or am I missing something?